# Не получилось ассоциировать вопрос

Tags: поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов

[Комментарий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/665125/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%89%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%be%d1%82-%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9#comment962014_665125) был написан 12 май в 16:28, но ассоциация вопросов [Как защитить файл от фиксации изменений?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/665125/178988) и https://stackoverflow.com/q/43940239/4928642 до сих пор не выполнена.

Comment: А вообще может ссылка должна быть на оригинальный вопрос, а не дубликат?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, вроде в других местах на дубликаты работало?

Comment: Я не про техническую возможность, а про правила, что должны быть вопросы с принятым ответом, популярные и т.д.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, так у нас-то как раз принятый ответ есть, а на enSO нет. Вообще, можно было бы множественные ассоциации в таких случаях.

Comment: Хочу правила ассоциации обсудить в [вопросе](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5315/220571). У меня нет какой-то позиции по этому поводу, просто хочу понять правила.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это не технический дефект, а организационный. На данный момент, для обновления ассоциаций (точнее, для появления ссылки в сообществе на английском языке) необходимо отправить запрос моим коллегам, чего я давно не делал. Обновимся к концу недели, как ранее планировали. Большое спасибо за указание на недочет!