# Кто модерирует ассоциации и как это будет происходить в будущем?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов

У нас есть возможность делать ассоциации, но кто определяет верна ассоциация или нет?

Если ли возможность отменять несправедливые ассоциации? Кто принимает решения о правомерности каждой ассоциации?

Что надо будет делать обычным пользователям (пока чисто гипотетический вопрос), если не согласен с ассоциацией?

Comment: По-моему, ты торопишься. Ассоциация по-прежнему ещё не является частью функциональности сайта, а до этого единственный вариант - писать Николасу в чате.

Comment: @Qwertiy, Не согласен, это **уже** часть функциональности, пусть даже и доступной в урезанном виде, иначе, к примеру, [ваш вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5304/220571) не существовал бы. И механизмы можно и, мне кажется, нужно обсуждать уже сейчас.

Comment: Нет, это работает через отдельную утилиту, которую кто-то запускает руками, а потом руками в коде SO прописывает (ну или в конфиге). Вообще никакой связанной функциональности (кроме отображения сообщения) на сайте вообще нет, соответственно обсуждать, кто какими правами и возможностями обладает, не представляется возможным. А в плане того, как это должно быть - полагаю, что-то типа варианта с дубликатами - автор, или обладатель золотой метки, или несколько пользователей. Или вопрос задан одним пользователем на обоих сайтах, тогда один голос любого пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Что надо будет делать обычным пользователям (пока чисто гипотетический вопрос), если не согласен с ассоциацией?

Вообще такой проблемы ранее не возникало. Но давайте подумаем.

Чисто технически, чтобы устранить некорректную ассоциацию, сейчас нужно добиться удаления соответствующего комментария. Традиционный способ организации такого воздействия со стороны обычных участников — тревога на комментарий. Ввиду исключительности ситуации (функциональность ассоциаций сейчас "приклеена сбоку") это должна быть **тревога для модератора**, иначе система может сделать неверные выводы.

Но этот вариант исключает общественные обсуждения. Если, конечно, модератор их явно не инициирует, к примеру, [в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462/stack-overflow--). Если модераторам будет не влом*, то это работоспособный вариант. Если такие проблемы будут возникать часто, можно выделить отдельную комнату.

И изменения проявятся не мгновенно, а только после очередного обновления ассоциаций. Оно делается периодически, не слишком часто.

---

А будь это интегрировано в движок SO, скорее всего была бы отдельная очередь проверок, доступная участникам с определённого уровня репутации **в каждом из участвующих в ассоциации сообществ**, куда попадали бы вопросы, получившие на соответствующие комментарии тревоги о некорректной ассоциации.

---

* *Это завуалированный вопрос к модераторам.*

Comment: Модератор не поможет - нужен именно Николас, насколько я представляю. Или, откуда информация, что удаление комментария ведёт к удалению ассоциации?

Comment: @Qwertiy вполне себе поможет, модераторы могут грохать комментарии, участие Николаса (и, возможно, не только его) нужно только для "вступления изменений в силу". А инфа из того, как инструменты ассоциации работали ранее -- нужно было оставлять комментарий в определённом формате вручную. А инструменты, запущенные позднее, просто отыскивают их среди всех по формату. По этой причине, кстати, обновление нельзя делать часто, т. к. оно реализовано очень технически неэффективно, но как тестовая фича годится.

Comment: Отыскивают всё заново? Если бы я эту утилиту делал, я бы сканировал только более новые комментарии по сравнению с прошлым запуском и добавлял результат к уже имеющемуся.

Comment: @Qwertiy возможно, так и происходит, но ситуации это не меняет.

Comment: Как раз меняет. Если сканируются только новые, то старые ассоциации не удалятся ;)

Comment: @Qwertiy хорошо, давайте подтвердим или опровергнем. Подгружайте навыки Python в кэш :) https://github.com/chabanovsky/so_association_tools

Comment: @Qwertiy, собственно ассоциация - это запись в бд и Nicolas просто вручную (запросом) обновляет строки

Comment: @Grundy, прикольно, а я думал, оно через SO-api работает, а там же лимит на число запросов в секунду.

Comment: @Qwertiy, не, через SO-api вот сайт, который может _написать от имени тебя_ комментарий :) ну и соответственно подгрузка вопросов и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy насколько я помню, там даже не запись в БД, а здоровенная строка из записей типа `en-id:ru-id` с разделителями, которая (дальше уже моя угадайка) разворачивается в мап при запуске.

Comment: @D-side, надо у Николаса уточнить :-D

Comment: @Grundy, строка в сформированном виде отправляется куда-то в конфиг SO - это где-то писалось. А дальше может и в map :)

Comment: @Qwertiy удаление комментария _ведет_ к удалению ассоциации при обновлении. То есть, каждый раз, перед обновлением, я выполняю SQL–запрос по базе и выгребаю все не удаленные комментарии с меткой `ассоциация`.

Comment: @D-side, на данный момент планируется, что в будущем это будет именно дополнительная очередь в очередях проверок.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, ясно. Спасибо за информацию!

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky отлично, угадал :) Спасибо за подтверждение!