# Какие вопросы можно и стоит ассоциировать?

Tags: обсуждение, поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов

Вопрос возника из-за [другого вопроса](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5304/220571). Там были чисто технические проблемы с ассоциацией с дубликатом без принятого ответа.

Я спрашиваю не про техническую возможность. Я хочу уточнить как правильно.

**Общий вопрос: какие вопросы и с какими можно ассоциировать, а когда ассоциация недопустима?**

Частные вопросы, вытекающие из общего:

1. Можно ли ассоциировать с закрытым вопросом? В также частности неясно можно ли ассоциировать с дубликатом. Вообще такое нередко бывает на enSO, что вопрос отмечается дубликатом когда очень смутно похож на некий другой (поэтому возможно будет иногда и полезно будет создавать ассоциацию именно на дубликат).
2. Можно ли ассоциировать с вопросом без принятого ответа? Или без ответов? Или есть ответы, но они какие-то некачественные? Или они некачественные или устаревшие, но вопрос закрыт?
3. Можно ли ассоциировать с вопросом с нулевым или отрицательным рейтингом? Некоторые высоко оценённые вопросы у нас, могут напротив уходить в минуса или быть проигнорированы на enSO (надеюсь, с этим никто спорить не будет).
4. Можно ли ассоциировать похожие вопросы но не 100% идентичные? Если да, то кто определяет "степень схожести"?

Также отсюда вытекают [следующий вопрос, связанный с модерацией ассоциаций](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5314/220571).

Comment: С закрытым на каком из сайтов? Сейчас ассоциация ведёт только в нашу сторону, поэтому не вижу причин, почему на enSO вопрос должен быть открыт.

Comment: @Qwertiy Возможно, это просто недоработка или просто временные трудности, что у нас не отображаются ассоциации в другую сторону.

Comment: Насколько я помню, при переходе по ссылке на закрытый как дубликат вопрос, если у него нет ответов, сработает автоматический редирект. А если ответы у него всё же есть, то как более точная ассоциация он будет удобнее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ответ на основной вопрос:

#### Предлагайте ваши варианты!

Приложение для ассоциации вопросов было сделано исключительно для того, чтобы мы могли попробовать ассоциацию, предложить свои идеи и быстро их реализовать/проверить.

Все ответы далее можно рассматривать, как ответы обычного участника заинтересованного в развитии проекта.

---

1. Вероятно, не стоит давать возможность ассоциировать закрытые вопросы. Если вопрос закрывающийся как дубликат имел ассоциацию, то ассоциацию автоматически стоит менять на основной вопрос. Ассоциация, по сути – это назначение вопросов–дубликатов написанных на разных языках. Связь должна существовать между оригинальными вопросами на каждом из сайтов.
2. Одна из основных идей ассоциаций – более качественно структурировать базу знаний, чтобы повысить доступность знаний. Как результат, на мой взгляд, в финальной версии функционала возможность ассоциации вопросов без ответов должна быть, но если вопрос на русском языке не имеет ответов (а также в случае наличия ответов только с отрицательным рейтингом), то он не должен быть показан на англоязычном сайте. То есть связь должна быть всегда, но отображение меняться в зависимости от качества знаний.
3. Вопрос – это ключ к знаниям. Ассоциациями мы увеличиваем доступность знаний. В общем случае, плохой ключ не портит качественных знаний (как минимум, минус можно получить только лишь за плохое оформление вопроса). Как результат, на ассоциацию должен влиять только рейтинг ответов, а не вопросов.
4. Объединять стоит только те вопросы, которые, будь они на одном языке, вы бы закрыли как дубликаты. Решение, как и всегда, принимает сообщество большинством голосов.

Comment: По первому пункту - авторедирект же? А если у закрытого есть ответы, то надо оставлять на его.

Comment: Дубликаты могут быть множественными - с ассоциациями это планируется?

Comment: Предлагаю разрешать ассоциации с закрытыми вопросами, кроме причин, к примеру "непонятна суть вопроса". Дубликаты иногда на enSO бывают очень смутно похожи. Поэтому если сделать ассоциацию с недубликатом, то это может противоречить пункту 4. "Субъективные", оффтопик, "слишком широкие" предлагаю разрешить  так как они могут быть вполне допустимы на нашем сайте.

Comment: @Qwertiy Опять же, как мы решим. Пока, на мой взгляд, отношение должно быть 1 к 1.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваши идеи отдельным ответом!

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, а смысл непонятные запрещать? Т. е. ситуация: кто-то обнаружил закрытый по любой причине вопрос и из него перешёл на такой же на другом сайте. Есть или причины ограничивать его в этом просто из-за того, что на одном из сайтов вопрос закрыт? А ещё состояние закрытости может меняться с течением времени.

Comment: @Qwertiy проблема в [автоматическом удалении вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392/). Если есть серьезные причины полагать, что вопрос будет закрыт, в ассоциации просто нет смысла.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Сделано как ответ.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, а не должно ли это сводиться к тому, что просто не отображать ассоциацию?

Comment: @Qwertiy Если вопрос на сайте англоязычного сообщества будет удален, ассоциацию будет негде показывать.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю разрешать ассоциации с закрытыми вопросами, кроме причин, указывающих на неадекватность и бесполезность вопроса, к примеру "непонятна суть вопроса". Да и то искусственно создавать это ограничение не вижу смысла.

"Субъективные", оффтопик, "слишком широкие" предлагаю разрешить так как они могут быть вполне допустимы на нашем сайте.

Дубликаты иногда на enSO бывают очень смутно похожи. Поэтому если сделать ассоциацию с недубликатом, то это может противоречить пункту 4. Также может быть такая ситуация когда вопросы-дубликаты скорее похожи, но не являются полными дубликатами. И если к дубликату имеет смысл применить ассоциацию, то по отношению к оригиналу это будет не совсем верно.

Comment: Продублирую комментарий: А смысл непонятные запрещать? Т. е. ситуация: кто-то обнаружил закрытый по любой причине вопрос и из него перешёл на такой же на другом сайте. Есть или причины ограничивать его в этом просто из-за того, что на одном из сайтов вопрос закрыт? А ещё состояние закрытости может меняться с течением времени.

Comment: @Qwertiy Я слово "запрещать" не говорил ни в ответе, ни в комментарии. Просто нежелательно такие вопросы ассоциировать. 
Пусть будет технически можно, но минимум в 99% случаев не нужно. Скажем так: пусть это не привествуется.

Comment: @Qwertiy Кстати написал ещё "Да и то искусственно создавать это ограничение не вижу смысла."