# Мои ассоциации не работают :(

Tags: поддержка, ассоциация-вопросов

Я заметил, что некоторые мои комментарии с ключевым словом «ассоциация» не интерпретируются, и на английском Stack Overflow ссылка на русский вариант не появляется. С чем могу быть связаны эти проблемы?

Примеры нерабочих ассоциаций:

- [Какое может быть практическое обоснование такой комбинации switch и while?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632181/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-switch-%d0%b8-while#comment910202_632181)
- [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0#comment910197_554290)
- [Как создать репозиторий на GitHub через командную строку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/504578/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b0-github-%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83#comment910016_504578)
- [Как игнорировать файлы только в локальном репозитории?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/448215/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b8#comment909989_448215)
- [Как реализовать листание в боте для Telegram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632630/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-telegram#comment909952_632630)
- [Что значит аргумент @{u} в Git?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/263414/%d0%a7%d1%82%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82-%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b3%d1%83%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82-u-%d0%b2-git#comment976269_263414)
- [Как разобрать произвольную ссылку на составляющие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/455974/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%8e-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b5#comment974570_455974)
- [Как сохранить вывод любой команды в файл и сразу же увидеть его в терминале?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/293567/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4-%d0%bb%d1%8e%d0%b1%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d1%83%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5#comment944359_293567)

Comment: Мы действительно, как я понимаю, не обновили настройки. С другой стороны, посмотрел ваши ассоциации и заметил, что вы иногда назначаете ассоциацию не на вопрос, а на ответ! Пожалуйста, назначайте ассоциации именно на вопрос, а не на ответ, иначе они не будут работать даже после обновления настроек сайта.

Comment: На всякий случай отпишусь, что ассоциации обновляли уже несколько раз. Если ошибок действительно нет, то ваши ассоциации должны быть давно доступны!

Comment: Да, они и самом деле уже заработали. Спасибо! Просто я тогда думал, что какой-то неправильный формат использовал, ну может там, пробелы лишние...

Answer (score 2):

1. [Не получилось ассоциировать вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5304/178988)
2. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=37884660#37884660

   > Добрый день! К сожалению, не успел обновить ассоциации в пятницу. Занес себе в список дел первым делом на завтра (вторник) обновить статистику и загрузить все дело в движок. Обязательно буду держать вас в курсе!
3. https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/22462?m=37908647#37908647

   > Я обновил ассоциации на сервере. Как только Штаты проснуться, попрошу ребят обновить настройки сайта. Еще раз спасибо за напоминание!

Видимо, настройки сайта ещё не обновили...

Comment: Но уже прошла неделя после ответа Николая Чабановского. Кроме того, у меня там есть комментарии, которым уже месяца три...

Comment: Последнее сообщение в чате - вчерашнее. Про 3 месяца не в курсе, может Николас пояснит.